# Android listview is not fluid when i use font from Assets

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fonts

I use this code to set Roboto font to a Textview for each item if my list.

It works fine but when i scrolml the list, it's not fluid whereas with default font, the list is verry fluid when i scroll.

```
TextView premiereLettre = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.premiere_lettre);
Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
premiereLettre.setTypeface(face);
```

What is the problem ?

Can i make an enhancement for this code ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that you create `TextView` object, and most importantly a `Typeface` object each time you create a row. Create them once in your class (you can use `ViewHolder` for your `TextView`, and a class level variable for `Typeface` that you instantiate in your constructor)

Comment: Yes, it was the problem :) Thanks a lot !